# Disconnecting a graph: How do I calculate the expectation of this event?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, graph-theory, expected-value

I'm struggling with calculating the expectation of this event. Say we're studying a graph where each nodes has an associated random variable $X_v$, representing the time it takes for node $v$ to "fail". When a node fails, it disappears from the graph. We're interested in failure events that disconnect the graph.

[image: Wheel graph on 6 vertices]

We look at the example in the attached graph, which is the wheel graph on 6 graph. This graph is 3-vertex-connected, which means we need at least 3 nodes to fail to increase its number of connected components. The failure events involving exactly 3 vertices in this particular graph are exactly: [0, 2, 5], [0, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], and [2, 4, 5].
Assuming we know the distributions $X_v$ for each vertex of the graph, how would we go about calculating the distribution/expectation of the failure time for the graph (i.e. the time it takes for the graph to get disconnected? Mathematically, you could phrase the failure event here as $$min \{max\{X_0, X_2, X_5\}, max\{X_0, X_3, X_5\}, max\{X_1, X_3, X_5\}, max\{X_1, X_4, X_5\}, max\{X_2, X_4, X_5\} \}$$, but the events that make up this larger event are pretty dependent on one another.
More generally, how do we account for all possible failure events?

Comment: All depend on $X_5$ so I would start by marginalizing that variable and then computing the conditional distributions of the rest. Computing the distribution of the maximum of two variables is not difficult (you can condition on the event that one is larger than the other for example).

Comment: It's clear how this could be done by hand. A failure in $X_5$ is needed for any failure event to occur. Then you just compute the max of two random variables like you said. What I'm looking for, though, is an algorithmic way to do this. Like if I were to be given a graph and was able to deduce a list of its potential minimal failure events, formulating them like the expression above, how would one be able to compute the properties of the resulting expression, i.e. its distribution and expectation for example.